# Hg plug-in for Visual Studio to have in editor "Blame" or "Annotate"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, mercurial, annotate, visualhg

We're using Hg with Visual studio 2010. I'd like to be able to see who has edited the code from the editor with out having to fire up VisualHg or the command prompt.

Does anyone know of a plug-in that shows the users in the margin of the the editor?

Even my annotate function with VisualHG only shows change sets, then you have to look up who committed that change set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VisualHg does show the user who committed the change. You can find the `Annotate File` function by right clicking on the document's tab or by right clicking on the document in the solution explorer.  When you choose this option, you get the TortoiseHg Annotate window which looks like this:

[image: Annotate Screenshot]

If you hover over a line of source in the right hand window, the status bar text changes to say who made the change, the local revision number of the changeset, how long ago it was committed and the first line of the message.  You can't hover over the line number or revision number gutter columns, the mouse needs to be over the actual source for the status text to change.

This is with TortoiseHg 2.3.1 and VisualHg 1.1.5.

Comment: That sounds like it will suit me perfectly, I've had a look on my set up, and can't see it, I'd really appreciate if you could post how to get it, or a screen shot or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on holiday and won't be able to look until next week but I'll make a note to check for you when I can.

Comment: I've added the extra details now.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this is not quite what I am looking for but its a good work around in lieu of something in the editor itself.